# How to restore normal flow after \filbreak

Tags: formatting, page-breaking

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1-4]\filbreak
  \textbf{This should fit on page 1}~\lipsum[5]\filbreak\lipsum[6-10]\filbreak
  \textbf{This should not fit on page 2}~\lipsum[11-12]\filbreak\lipsum[13-19]
\end{document}
```

The problem arises with the **last** `\filbreak` in this example. It flushes `\lipsum[13-19]` to the next page. I want to replace the last `\filbreak` it with a command `\stopfilbreak`, so that since `\lipsum[11-12]` actualy didn't fit on page 2, then it would put `\lipsum[11-12]` on page 3 with `\lipsum[13-19]` following it (on page 3). Now it sets `\lipsum[13-19]` on page 4.

I want a command `\stopfilbreak` such that LaTeX interprets "fit the content between `\filbreak` and `\stopfilbreak` on the same page if possible, else break the page here and put it on a new page". The content to come after `\stopfilbreak` should not be affected.

That is: i want a command that restores the normal flow after use of `\filbreak`

---

Be aware that it might be so that what would go between `\filbreak` and `\stopfilbreak` could be larger than a pagewidth, so `minipage` would not work.

Below is some background info that I think might be helpful to answer my question:

---

### Background info

#### Purpose of `\filbreak`

The TeXbook says that `\filbreak` means roughly

> “Break the page here and fill the bottom with blank space, unless there is room for more copy that is itself followed by \filbreak.”

That is, if we consider content that is "enclosed" by `\filbreak`s, it inserts this content if there is room on the page, but goes to the next page if there is no room.

#### `\filbreak` in practice

`\filbreak` is defined by `\par\vfil\penalty-200\vfilneg`. As I understand it, this finishes up the current paragraph, then fills the page with stretchable whitespace and then, at the bottom of the page/top of new page it says that "breaking" here is cheap. If the program then decides to break here, then the `\vfilneg` doesn't do anything because there is no `\vfil` to "neg", but if it doesn't then `\vfilneg` puts the "cursor" back.

---

I'm not using `\filbreak` as it was purposed. Everything in my VC-example works as expected, which indicates that I might be asking the wrong question?

Comment: I think your understanding of `\filbreak` is mistaken or at least imprecise. It does not really check or insert anything; it merely inserts a particular sequence of glue and penalties, which are used by the page builder whenever it decides to look for appropriate places to break the page. Rather than go by the informal description in The TeXbook, see the definition you've included. Anyway, it's not clear what you want exactly: where do you want the page breaks to happen / what would you like the general behaviour to be?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: I see how it could seem like my understanding of `\filbreak` is wrong. I get that it doesn't "check" anything, I just had problems wording this, which results in that my description of how `\filbreak` works is imprecise. Maybe it's just confusing to have the **Background info** in there? 

I suspect you missed the "TL;DR"-section in the top (maybe because you read all the rest)? I thought it was quite clear there what I wanted to achieve. If I'm wrong, and you did read it, let me know what is unclear so I can clarify!

Comment: It may help to explain again what you want in different words (i.e. show where the page breaks go, in your example, and why). Because: What does _“the height of \lipsum[5] is evaluated for inserting space, and then insert the upcoming as if there was nothing happening”_ mean? (Because height is never evaluated… and what does “nothing happening” mean.) Similarly, not clear what _“I want a command \endfilbreak to check only the "height" of \lipsum[5] and then insert the upcoming as if there was nothing happening”_ means.

Comment: I think I've cleared it up now in the question?

Comment: I deleted my answer, because it was completely wrong.  The value of `\outputpenalty` cannot be used in that way to discriminate the two cases.

Comment: It's definitely clearer now, and @GuM seems to have understood your question, but unfortunately it's not clear to me what the problem is. In your example MWE at the top, if I remove `\endfilbreak` (or replace/define it with nothing), then I get 3 pages, with 1–4 on the first page, 5–9 on the second page, and 10 on the third page. So your example does not actually illustrate any problem, because it seems that an empty definition of `\endfilbreak` matches the thing you want (“`\lipsum[6-10]` should always come right after `\lipsum[5]`”). Do you have a more illuminating example perhaps?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR You are completely right in regards to the MWE. I'm sorry I made such a messy and unclear question. Again: I have updated it, and please let me know if it's readable now.

The comment about GuM not understanding the question was from his previous answer. His answer now works as expected! :)

Comment: It's getting clearer, and I'm sorry to keep nagging you about this especially when @GuM seems to have understood your question and given you what you want. There are two problems I still face: (1) I think in _“with `\lipsum[13-19]` preceding it (on page 3)”_ you mean “following” instead of “preceding” (the opposite). Otherwise it seems magical…. (2) You want to replace the last `\filbreak` with a `\stopfilbreak`, but it is still the case that if I replace the last `\filbreak` with nothing, then everything seems to satisfy your requirements. So empty definition of `\stopfilbreak` still works?

Comment: I did men preceding and not following, yes. Thanks. I guess an empty filbreak would technically work in this case. However, you don't a priori know whether `\lipsum[11-12]` would fit or not.

Comment: Ah I see; finally I understand! (I think.) Your question is the following: you intend to enclose some stuff (like `\lipsum[11-12]`) within some macros, with the intended meaning being: “fit this stuff on the same page if possible, else break the page here and put it on a new page”. And of course, what comes later should not be affected. Is that correct? (You propose `\filbreak ...\stopfilbreak` as the intended form of these macros, but if I understand your true goal correctly, then you just care about these semantics/behaviour, and the macros don't necessarily have to take this exact form.)

Comment: Yes. Exactly. It does not __have__ to be `\filbreak` used, but to my use, having them as macros are necessary. I hope it's okay with you if I insert your formulation into my question?

Comment: Yes sure, of course. BTW I think a related question has been [asked before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348299/prevent-widowing-orphaning-of-sections-that-can-fit-on-one-page), with a great answer by @GuM there as well. (A very different approach though.) Maybe he can elaborate how the approaches differ, if he feels up to it. Thanks for your patience and making the question clear for me. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had previously posted, and subsequently deleted, an answer that was completely wrong; now I’m replacing it with the following one, which not only makes at least some sense, but also seems to work as expected! (:-)

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter

\@ifdefinable\@My@filbreak@counter{\newcount\@My@filbreak@counter}
\global \@My@filbreak@counter = 0
\@ifdefinable\@My@filbreak@mark{\newmarks\@My@filbreak@mark}

\renewcommand*\filbreak{%
    \par
    \global \advance \@My@filbreak@counter \@ne
    \marks\@My@filbreak@mark{\number\@My@filbreak@counter}%
    \vfil
    \penalty -200
    \vfilneg
}

\newcommand*\@My@finish@stopfilbreak{}

\newcommand*\stopfilbreak{%
    \par
    \ifnum \prevdepth >\@m \else \prevdepth \z@ \fi
    \nobreak \null
    \nobreak \vskip -\baselineskip
    \penalty \z@
    \begingroup
        \output{%
            % \typeout{>>> \topmarks\@My@filbreak@mark
            %         \space vs \number\@My@filbreak@counter}%
            \typeout{t: \the\pagetotal, g: \the\pagegoal}%
            \unvbox\@cclv
            \ifnum 0\topmarks\@My@filbreak@mark <\@My@filbreak@counter
                % the last "\filbreak" is still on the current page
                \gdef\@My@finish@stopfilbreak{%
                    \vfil\break % force page break
                }%
            \else
                % the page has changed since the last "\filbreak"
                \gdef\@My@finish@stopfilbreak{%
                    \penalty\z@ % allow page break but don't force it
                }%
            \fi
        }%
        \break
    \endgroup
    \@My@finish@stopfilbreak
}

\makeatother

\newcommand*{\mylipsum}[1]{\par\textbf{#1}~-- \lipsum*[#1]\par}

% \tracingpages = 1



\begin{document}
    \mylipsum{1}
    \filbreak
    \mylipsum{2}
    \filbreak
    \mylipsum{3}
    \filbreak
    \mylipsum{4}
    \filbreak
    \mylipsum{5}
    \filbreak
    \mylipsum{6}
    \filbreak
    \mylipsum{7}
    \filbreak
    \mylipsum{8}
    \mylipsum{9}
    \mylipsum{10}
    % \mylipsum{11}
    \indent One.\par
    \indent Two.\par
    \indent Three.\par
    \indent Four.\par
    % \indent Five.\par
    % \indent Six.\par
    % \mylipsum{12}
    \stopfilbreak
    \mylipsum{13}
    \mylipsum{14}
    \mylipsum{15}
    \mylipsum{16}
\end{document}
```

Try uncommenting the line that says `% \mylipsum{11}`, or the line that reads `% \indent Five.\par`.

I’m too weary, now, to explain in detail how the code works; perhaps I’ll review this answer tomorrow, for now I simply hint at the general idea.  We use a custom `\marks` system, namely `\marks\@my@filbreak@mark`, to detect if the last `\filbreak` before `\stopfilbreak` occurs on the same page as the latter, and if so we force a page break; otherwise, `\stopfilbreaks` inserts only a *permissible* breakpoint.

I’ve left the previous version of this answer accessible through the edit list so that everyboby can contemplate how incredibly stupid it was…

Comment: YASS! Perfect! I would **love** it if you'd explain how it works too at some point! Thanks!

Comment: It works when I put it in my examples and I can't find anything wrong in a usecase, however, in the first `\gdef\@My@finish@stopfilbreak` I'm not really sure if it does what I ask? I _might_ have been a bit quick to accept this answer, heh ':)

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman: You mean, the action taken when the last `\filbreak` is still on the same page?  It can be changed: what would you like to occur, intstead of a page break being forced?

Comment: I changed my mind. I think it does exactly what it's supposed to! Maybe. I'll let you know when I've figured it all out ':)