# Add a box around text

Tags: formatting, box

I am trying to add text inside a box like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# This is the section I am looking to do.

Paragraph here

1. point 1
1. point 2
1. point 3
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am getting this:

[image]

But I really want this:

[image]

Basically, is there a way to format the text between these lines>

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you want to input that exact syntax (which looks like markdown syntax) or you just want that output?

Comment: Yes, it is markdown syntax, I use pandoc to convert markdown to PDF.  It would be best to use the syntax it is easier to work with, but if there is no way, I can use the regular latex syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use markdown syntax in LaTeX you can use, you guessed, the `markdown` package :-)

You just need to load the package and put the text in a `markdown` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{markdown}
\begin{document}
\begin{markdown}
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# This is the section I am looking to do.

Paragraph here

1. point 1
1. point 2
1. point 3

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\end{markdown}
\end{document}
```

and then compile the document with `-shell-escape` enabled. And the output will be:

> [image]

Notice however that there are some differences between proper markdown and the package. For instance, you need a blank line before and after the `----` lines to have them working properly.

Comment: Is there a way to keep the section between the two lines on the same page?

Comment: @user1135541 Not without changing the input a bit. Instead of a `\section` you would need a `\begin{section}`...`\end{section}` in order to have some control over the page breaking (see [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/348299/134574), for example). That would be possible, except in markdown there is no such thing as `\begin{section}` unless you misused some other feature, like code fences. You can, however, make the whole `markdown` environment stay on one single page by wrapping it into a `minipage` or using one of the environments from the linked thread.