# Automatically place listoffigures and listoftables on the same page ONLY IF they fit on one page

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, page-breaking

I am creating a template for documents that have lists of tables and figures.

Sometimes the **lists are long** and I simply use:

```
\listoftables
\listoffigures
```

At other times both **lists are short** and fit on one page, then I manually update the code to:

```
\listoftables
{\let\clearpage\relax \listoffigures}
```

Is it possible to automate this and place the lists on the same page ONLY IF they fit on one page?

The [closest solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348299/prevent-widowing-orphaning-of-sections-that-can-fit-on-one-page) I have found is a bit over my head. Not sure how to adapt it to my case, and maybe there is a simpler way to do it?

Comment: What should happen if listoftables is one line long and listofigures is longer the the remaining of the page? And the opposite?

Comment: @Simon Dispa If listoffigures is longer than the remaining of the page or vice versa, then it should start on a new page.